Issue while trying to access a ConfigMap defined in a subchart from its parent chart in Helm
parent-chart/
├── Chart.yaml
├── values.yaml
└── templates/
        └── dir/
              └── exm-dpl.yaml
└── subchart/
        └──child
             ├── Chart.yaml
             ├── values.yaml
             └── templates/
                  └── sth-cm.yaml

I want to access in exm-dpl.yaml file checksum of sth-cm.yaml:
checksum.config.sth: {{ include ( path ) | sha256sum }}
How can I do it ? There is no option to point direct path, making value with a path is also not working. There is information that there is no template associated with template "gotpl"
